# Xamarin android : Having invalid connectionString for azure push notification

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification

I am using the connection string from azure portal for the push notification. When I try calling the notificationhub, I received this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connection string: Error parsing connection string: Missing character =. Position 21.
>       at com.microsoft.windowsazure

Package I used:

> using Firebase.Iid;
>   using Firebase.Messaging;
>   using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq; 
>   using Tux.Core.Constants;
>   using System.Linq;
>   using System.Collections.Generic;
>   using Tux.Core.Network.Utility; 
>   using WindowsAzure.Messaging;

Comment: Any luck getting this working?  I'm having the same issue?
I found this, and I had my parameters backwards.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs/blob/master/Android/notification-hubs-sdk/src/main/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/messaging/NotificationHub.java

Comment: I am not sure is it the same solution... What I have remembered, I put the name of the notification then the connectionstring. Coz the intellisense didn't tell me the actual what argument to put in.

Comment: It's working now, since I put the params in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the value of your connection string.
You could following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm#configure-your-notification-hub) to get the correct connection string. Make sure you are not using the connection string for `DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature`.

And the code for `NotificationHub`:

```
NotificationHub hub = new NotificationHub("Name", "connection string", this);
```